# three.js and openlayers coordinates don't line up

Tags: three.js, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm using three.js on a separate canvas on top of a openlayers map. the way I synchronize the view of the map and the three.js camera (which looks straight down onto the map) looks like this:

```
// calculate how far away the camera needs to be, to
// see this part of the map
function distanceFromExtentAndFOV(h, vFOV) {
    return h / (2 * Math.tan(vFOV / 2));
}

// keep three.js camera in sync with visible part of openlayers map
function updateThreeCam(
    group, // three.js group, containing camera
    view, // ol view
    map // ol map
) {
    extent = getViewExtent(view, map);
    const h = ol.extent.getHeight(extent);
    mapCenter = ol.extent.getCenter(extent);
    camDist = distanceFromExtentAndFOV(h, constants.CAM_V_FOV_RAD);
    const pos = [...mapCenter, camDist];
    group.position.set(...pos);
    group.updateMatrixWorld();
}

// whenever view changes, update three.js camera
view.on('change:center', (event) => {
    updateThreeCam(group, event.target, map);
});
view.on('change:resolution', (event) => {
    updateThreeCam(group, event.target, map);
});
updateThreeCam(group, view, map);
```

I'm using three.js for custom animations of objects, that in the end land on the ground. however, when I turn the objects into openlayers features, the original three.js objects and the features don't line up perfectly (although their position coordinates are exactly the same). — also, when you pan, you can see that s.th. is slightly off.

[image]

```
// turn three.js planes into openlayers features:
const features = rects.map((rect) => {
    const point = new ol.geom.Point([
        rect.position.x, 
        tect.position.y
    ]);
    return new ol.Feature(point);
});
vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
```

as I am pretty sure that my the code for synchronizing three.js and ol is correct, I am not really sure what what is going wrong. am I missing s.th. here?

Comment: What's the fidelity of the pixel position from ol? meaning, what is the pixel extents of the html plane, is the window 1024, 512? The smaller the window, the more deviation will occur. I personally would send the point position from ol as a percentage left and top. Are you sure the browser isn't zoomed in or out?  Have you checked the map plane aspect ratio? Is it == to the ol Window aspect ratio?

Comment: turns out the position of the camera (relative to the parent group) was not what it was supposed to be 

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are using `PerspectiveCamera` and that will change the size/position based on depth. Try `OrtographicCamera` instead.

Comment: yes, I am using `PerspectiveCamera` (mainly because I need a realistic foreshortening effect). `OrtographicCamera` would certainly avoid the problem, but it's not really an option for what I want to do.

Comment: It looks like the way camera moves things depending on depth is your problem. You can see that on the left side the dots are too far to the left. On the right it is too far to the right. I guess you can try to play with the depth values of your dots to make it correct.